# Codeigniter PHPwork

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf, phpword

I have one question ^^ ! I use phpword, tcpdf with codeigniter. I want (first and this first part is good) to write in word document (for change info or another). After this, i want to convert word to PDF and finally download it. When i search in docuementation (phpword) i said it's possible with tcpdf. But when a try i have this error : (picture). (sorry for my bad english..). thanks [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eD1Ky.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iv3JY.png)

Comment: Please add your code direct to the question (copy paste it in), the same for you error. Images (and links especially) break over time and are not helpful at all

Comment: there are plenty of resources on google if you search for that specific error

Comment: Okay thanks and sorry for past code ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of this problem :

```
$PHPWord = $this->word; // New Word Document
        $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('assets/word/' . $select_info->attestation);
        $document->setValue('ID', $insert);
        $document->setValue('lastname', $select_info->nom);
        $document->setValue('name', $select_info->prenom);
        $document->setValue('date', date('d/m/Y'));
        $document->save('./test.docx');

        //Avec libraoffice convertir word to pdf

        shell_exec('start /wait soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "." "./test.docx"');
```

Install libreoffice and use this for convert, thanks for reply everyone